# Different text-search results between Chromium and Firefox

Tags: macos, firefox, browser, html, chromium

I'm searching for the string `global rule` on this page: [https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch4/ref-rule-properties](https://web.archive.org/web/20211028001417/https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch4/ref-rule-properties)

Chromium finds the text; Firefox does not.

#### Firefox

[image: Firefox]

Abbreviated HTML (as rendered by the browser):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section class="topic">
      <div>
        <p>
          s are called 
          <em>
            <span class="match">
              ::before
              global
            </span>
             
            <span class="match">
              ::before
              rule
            </span>
            s
          </em>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Chromium

[image: Chromium]

Abbreviated HTML (as rendered by the browser):

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <section class="topic">
      <div>
        <p>
          "s are called "
          <em>
            <span class="match">
              ::before
              "global"
            </span>
            <span class="match">
              ::before
              "rule"
            </span>
            "s"
          </em>
        </p>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that this exact HTML is only produced when navigating to this page after searching for the string "turn into global rule" in the website's global search, i.e. the webpage tags the terms in the page that matched your search term.

##### Two questions:

1. Is there some sleezy hack that I can do in Firefox so it will find the text? I'm thinking, perhaps there's some toggle in `about:config` where a user can opt into some experimental improved text search behavior, or something.
2. (Optional) What is the difference between the Firefox and Chromium text search implementations that might account for these different outcomes?

My gear:

- MacOS 12.0.1
- Intel x86_64
- Firefox (stable) 93.0
- Chromium 95.0.4638.54 (ungoogled-chromium build)

Comment: Its worth clarifying that to reproduce this problem you need to click on the search button at the top right of https://help.obdev.at/littlesnitch4/ref-rule-properties (not the internet-archive version in the post above), and searching for little rules, then clicking on the link "Anatomy of a rule"

Comment: So you are looking for a way to make firefox search ignore HTML?

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution to this.

I installed a plugin "Regex Search" by Mohd_PH - this enabled a small grey/green hexagon icon at the top right of the browser.  When I'm in the page in question I can click on the hexagon and enter "global rules" as a regex term and tick the "ignore html" option.   Search, then Highlight finds the text in the page and highlights it in a bright yellow.

I assume Chrome is stripping out HTML when it does a keyword search while Firefox doesn't.

Comment: That's not it. But it's some combination of the different "reprocessing" of the HTML that each browser does, with whatever algorithm they use for searching strings.